# Talking about an achievement - "one of the harder thing's I've done"

Tags: superlatives, comparative

Is it correct, when talking about an achievement, to say something was:

> "...one of the harder things I've done."

I know I should probably say:

> "...one of the hardest things I've done"

But for some reason it almost feels correct to just say it in comparative.  Any thoughts?

Comment: is there any reason you think this is wrong? I assume it was your intention to change the meaning slightly, given that you have mentioned it's comparative

Comment: Harder than what? Shouldn't the sentence be "...one of the hard things I've done" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [one of the more fascinating](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/one-of-the-more-fascinating)

Comment: As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+the+more%2Cone+of+the+most&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0) shows, the construction ***one of the [superlative]*** is far more common than ***one of the [comparative]***. But both forms are perfectly valid, and in practice they usually mean the same thing (superlative is just "more emphatic").

Comment: @WeatherVane: Harder than the things I've done that ***weren't*** as hard as the one being spoken of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers has the usage overflowed from ad-speak? "Our ice-cream is softer".

Comment: @WeatherVane: I was going to say I didn't see why we should suppose an "origin" for ***one of [comparative]***, whether or not somehow "derived" from ***one of [superlative]***. I'd have thought both versions would always have been around. But I just searched Google Books for various likely examples, such as *one of [the / our / his / my] [more, less, higher / lower / etc.* with DateRange restricted to C19 or earlier. I was more than a bit surprised that I couldn't find any.

Answer (score -3):

The correct sentence is:
"..one of the hardest things I've done"
You always use superlatives in this kind of sentence, when you are talking in general about the things you have ever done:
like for example : "..one of the best " (instead it would be WRONG to say "one of the better")

If you were not talking in general, but comparing two peculiar situations you could say:
"Doing this was harder than doing that"

Comment: Many say it's not quite [WRONG](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+the+better+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20better%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Incorrect; you can definitely say “that was one of the harder things that I have done.”